# Is there an alternative to "aren't I?"

Tags: grammaticality

"Aren't I" sounds wrong to say, but as far as I know there are no alternatives. Does anyone have a quick, compact alternative to "aren't I" that sounds more grammatically correct?

Thank you so much to anyone who answers or reads this in general.

Comment: A simple option is *"am I not...?"* to start a question. For example, *"Am I not the person you are looking for?"*. However, *"Aren't I?"* is great when used alone, such as in response to *"You're not the person I'm looking for."*

Comment: Well, *ain't I?* is an option, especially since *ain't* began life a contraction of *am not*. But enjoy convincing everyone else of that.

Comment: I've heard uses of "Amn't" I many times (and I have to confess to sometimes using it in conversation myself), although I just got a red line, so it's probably not fully formally accepted. Try searching a bit about "amn't".

Comment: Instead of asserting that *"Aren't I" sounds wrong to say* — and the way you phrased that makes me suspect strongly that English is not your first language — you would have done better to first Google that term and/or do some actual research on a site like this, in order to assess for yourself how prevalent it is and how it is being used. As it stands, this is a worthless question because its premise is faulty: "Aren't" I is perfectly grammatical, and is also perfectly normal usage.

Answer (score 0):

Most used, and grammatically correct, would be 'am I not?'.

Comment: I strongly doubt the "most used" assertion.

Comment: What grammatically correct alternative would you consider to be used more?

Comment: I would say "Aren't I" is used more. Your assertion is clearly constructed to separate "most used" from "grammatically correct" as qualifiers.

Comment: The most used grammatically correct would be 'am I not'.  Since 'aren't I' is grammatically incorrect.  Are it not? ;)

Comment: Ah, but that's a different assertion to the one in your answer.

Comment: You think so.  The poster is specifically looking for an alternative to 'Aren't I'.  I am suggesting the most used, grammatically correct alternative to the incorrect phrase he's attempting to avoid.  It wouldn't be very helpful to suggest, stay with 'Aren't I', as it's the most used.